# Quicker way to manage data than using python with JSON

Tags: python, sql, json, database, performance

I am using python to scrape, store and plot the data on an odds website for later reference. Initially I am storing the data in numerous .csv files (every X minutes) which I then aggregate into larger json files (per day) for easier access.

The problem is that with the increasing number of events per day(>600), the speed at which the json files are manipulated becomes unacceptable (~35s to just load a single json file of the size of 95MB).

What would be another set-up which would be more efficient (in terms of speed)? Maybe using SQL alongside python?

Comment: Try using `pandas` with [`feather`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_feather.html). This will speed things up [quite a bit](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-best-format-to-save-pandas-data-414dca023e0d).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try another JSON library like [orjson](https://pypi.org/project/orjson/) instead of the standard one.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I will certainly give it a try since it brands itself the fastest Python library for JSON. However, I am not entirely sure that using JSON is the way to go.